# Optimize foreach loop in wordpress custom function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, action-scheduler

I have 4000+ products in multi site where i need to sync them with other sites so i tried with wp query but the problem is whenever i try to do that i got 500 internal server error. May be i need to optimize this script ?

```
function get_query_data($posts){
    foreach ($posts as $post){
        yield $post;
    }
}
// handle the ajax request
function sync_stock_action_fn()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpmis = new WPIMS();
    $paged = isset($_GET['paged']) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;
    $post_per_page = 200;
    $offset_start = 1;

    $offset = ($paged - 1) * $post_per_page + $offset_start;
    $args     = array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page, 'post_status' => array('publish', 'draft', 'private'), 'paged' => $paged, 'offset' => $offset);
    $total_synced_products = array();
    $products = new WP_Query($args);
    $t_products = count($products->posts);
    $no_of_paginations = ceil($t_products / $post_per_page);
    $count = 0;
    $location = array();
    foreach (get_query_data($products->posts) as $product) {
        $product_id = (int)$product->ID;
        $location = $wpmis->wpmis_get_location($product_id);
        $sku = get_post_meta($product_id, '_sku', true);
  
        $stock = get_post_meta($product_id, '_stock', true);
        $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
        $sites = array(1, 26,27,28);
        $d_sites = array();
        foreach ($sites as $site) {
            if ($site != $current_blog_id) {
                switch_to_blog($site);
                // GET PRODUCT BY SKU
                $p_id = $wpmis->wpmis_get_product_by_sku($sku);

                if ($p_id !== 0 && !empty($p_id)) {
                    wp_set_object_terms($p_id, $location, 'atum_location');
                    update_post_meta($p_id, '_stock', $stock);
                    $total_synced_products[] = $p_id;
                    $d_sites[] = $site;
                }
                restore_current_blog();
            }
        }
        
        $count++;
    }
    $results = array('total_synced' => count($total_synced_products), 'total_products' => $t_products, 'count' => $count, 'sites' => $d_sites);
    echo json_encode($results);
    exit;
}
```

i tried Generator function get_query_data  but it not help me out.

Kindly suggest

Comment: Often a 500 error causes an entry to be put in the error log. You might look for that.

Comment: Some time this script works and some time got error i am sure its memory exhausted. there is not any error in this script... i need to optimize less memory use this script please

Comment: Sometimes you can get your hosting service to increase the amount of RAM you can use. If this fails only sometimes, that's probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Already did that boss

Comment: Did you try enabling debug mode and check the error log, if any fatal error it will be captured in log. Looking at your tries it feels like there is one product which does not return a proper type which you trying to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, you can use an action scheduler plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/ and then process 50-100 products in a single batch.

Another way is using Ajax request where you process 50-100 products at once with a check of memory limit & time limit, if time or memory limit breaks, you break the process and send the current process index in response and ajax will start again after the no of products has been processed.

Complete Example is here you can find a php and js code here.

```
https://github.com/vijayhardaha/wp-bulk-process-template
```

Comment: Any example like how can we check memory limit break... Kindly give any example ?

Comment: I have a boilerplate here https://github.com/vijayhardaha/wp-bulk-process-template here you can find PHP and JS code to run bulk process with AJAX but this repository doesn't have runner functions code, so you'll have to write those on your own.

Comment: Kindly help me one more thing... Can we have any option to close browser and this ajax process running at backend ?

Comment: Sorry, that won't be possible using jQuery AJAX, you'll have to keep the window open. If you want to use background processing then you'll have to go with `action scheduler` or `wp_schedule_event` options.

Comment: I have request... Can you please make an quick example with wpdb query ? i did not able to understand with index, position how it will works kindly help me with that ... Thanks in advance

Comment: How can i handle offset, pagination with recycle and when memory limit exceed or time execution is exceed how script where that was break and it will start it from

Comment: It's hard to explain all the processes here. I will try to update the repo with the demo code when I will have time.

Comment: Okay thanks, Kindly update repo when you have a time then please update me

Answer (score 0):

Can you not decrease post per page, i think it will help to decrease server memory limit, like you are using  $post_per_page = 200; you can decrease it to 50 or so.

Comment: Sorry it not worked even i tried 30 :)

Answer (score 0):

Without directly seeing the code and the data that's being returned, this is a tough one to say, but my first instinct is to check whether you need that `get_query_data` function call.. Especially as a 'yield', I could see that generator function consuming a lot of memory.

You're main loop essentially has 3 `foreach` loops running recursively, which is probably going to choke out many shared hosting servers.

Do you have any way of determining WHICH products need synced, rather than all of them? Can you check against a last-modified timestamp or something similar?